# Use Cell info in a formula

Tags: excel, vba, date, excel-formula

I was wondering if it's possible to use info from a cell in creating a formula. Here's the situation;

```
A1 = Date (01/01/17)
A2 = Month from that date (January)
```

I have different worksheets in the book for every month so for January the sheet is called January.

Is it possible to create a formula where I can reference a cell in a page that corresponds to the month in `A2`.

So for example in A3 the formula would be `=January!A1`

But instead of Jan I want it to be dynamic so it would change to any month depending on what I input in previous cells.

Comment: `INDIRECT` is what you want

Answer (score 3):

In A2 to get the month try

`=TEXT(A1,"mmmm")`

and then in A3

`=INDIRECT(A2&"!A1")`

or you can cut out A2 altogether and use just

`=INDIRECT(TEXT(A1,"mmmm")&"!A1")`

Comment: Nice solution. I wish there was an easy way to do this without `INDIRECT`, but the only way I can think of to do this without `INDIRECT` is with a ton of nested `IF`s, eg. `= IF(MONTH(A1)=1,January!A1,IF(MONTH(A1)=2,February!A1...))` but that formula is unnecessarily long.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 A bit shorter with `CHOOSE` like `=CHOOSE(MONTH(A1),January!A1, February!A1,....

Comment: Ohhh, nice, didn't even know about `CHOOSE`.